# what doctrine should we accept?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is this site just for Bible-based questions and answers?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/is-this-site-just-for-bible-based-questions-and-answers)
>   [What literature do we consider to be foundational?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-literature-do-we-consider-to-be-foundational)

This is actually a topic that I need to be informed about because I wouldn't want to be short with somebody that's quoting from something other then the bible.

I want to propose that when it comes to scripture we keep this site exclusive to the 66 books of the bible.

It will be too hard to find the truth if Islam, Mormonism and Christians are all trying to answer with COMPLETELY different beliefs.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking about secular texts. I am talking about scripture specifically.

Comment: While my question wasn't about allowing just secular texts (none of the answers there interpreted that way), your question is also duplicated by [What literature do we consider to be foundational?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-literature-do-we-consider-to-be-foundational) and I thought [we already ruled out](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor) trying to vote people off the island for not talking about the right kind of Christianity.

Comment: ok I will rephrase my question you can close this one.

Comment: Voting to delete since not only is the a duplicate but the OP has publicly changed positions.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of commentaries, catechisms and many other resources that are useful for interpreting scripture and expressing doctrinal opinions that are scripturally based but not directly from the Bible.

This site will be much better if we allow people to quote from their catechisms, and other places. It would be foolish to claim we were an expert site on Christianity without the ability to cite commentary and other religious texts.